# Неверный порядок в структуре json(newtonsoft) c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

Я сохраняю в json-файл введённые данные. Так же есть блоки, которых может быть неограниченное количество(динамические), которые я добавляю по нажатии кнопки. Я привожу пример структуры и как создаются эти блоки на примере servicetype.
Моя проблема в том, что на первое место выходит динамические блоки, а статика оказывается ниже...(на скрине видно, то servicetype и measures... вверху, но мне надо, чтобы они шли по примеру, в распорядке, который написан в классе incident.) Можно ли так сделать и как ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
class Incident
{
    public string fincertId { get; set; }
    public string fixationAt { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public lawEnforcementRequest lawEnforcementRequest { get; set; }
    public string assistance { get; set; }
    public string vectorCode { get; set; }
    public List<serviceType> serviceType = new List<serviceType>();
    public string typeOfAttack { get; set; }
    public List<measuresAndRecomendations> measuresAndRecomendations = new List<measuresAndRecomendations>();
}



    private void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tableLayoutPanel3.SuspendLayout();
        tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount++;
        var label0 = new Label();
        label0.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 40);
        label0.Text = "Блок" + (b + 1).ToString();
        tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(label0, 0, tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount - 1);
        tableLayoutPanel3.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
        tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount++;
        var label = new Label();
        label.Text = "sourceId";
        tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(label, 0, tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount - 1);
        tableLayoutPanel3.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
        textBoxes.Add(new TextBox());
        textBoxes[o].Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(textBoxes[o], 1, tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount - 1);//добавили на форму 
        tableLayoutPanel3.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
        o++;
        tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount++;
        var label1 = new Label();
        label1.Text = "type";
        tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(label1, 0, tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount - 1);
        tableLayoutPanel3.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
        cCheckedLists.Add(new cCheckedListBox());
        cCheckedLists[b].Items.AddRange(variants);
        cCheckedLists[b].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(298, 150);
        cCheckedLists[b].Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(cCheckedLists[b], 1, tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount - 1);
        tableLayoutPanel3.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
        tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount++;
        var label2 = new Label();
        label2.Text = "name";
        tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(label2, 0, tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount - 1);
        tableLayoutPanel3.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
        textBoxes.Add(new TextBox());
        textBoxes[o].Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(textBoxes[o], 1, tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount - 1);//добавили на форму 
        tableLayoutPanel3.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
        tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount++;
        o++;
        var label3 = new Label();
        label3.Text = "version";
        tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(label3, 0, tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount - 1);
        tableLayoutPanel3.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
        textBoxes.Add(new TextBox());
        textBoxes[o].Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(textBoxes[o], 1, tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount - 1);//добавили на форму 
        tableLayoutPanel3.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
        o++;
        tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount++;
        var label4 = new Label();
        label4.Text = "description";
        tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(label4, 0, tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount - 1);
        tableLayoutPanel3.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
        textBoxes.Add(new TextBox());
        textBoxes[o].Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(textBoxes[o], 1, tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount - 1);//добавили на форму 
        tableLayoutPanel3.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
        tableLayoutPanel3.ResumeLayout();
        o++;
        b++;
    }


    private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage2; 
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();// это часть магии для сохранения файла,вывод окно с выбором куда и с каким именем сохранять. её просто копировать
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "JSON files(*.json)|*.json|All files(*.*)|*.*";
        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            return;
        }
        Incident incident = new Incident
        {
            fincertId = textBox1.Text,
            fixationAt = textBox9.Text,
            description = textBox10.Text,
            assistance = cCheckedListBox3.Text,
            vectorCode = cCheckedListBox4.Text,
            typeOfAttack = cCheckedListBox5.Text,
        };
            lawEnforcementRequest lawEnforcementRequest = new lawEnforcementRequest
    {
        addressed = cCheckedListBox1.Text,
        request = cCheckedListBox2.Text,
        number = textBox11.Text,
        numberTicket = textBox12.Text,
        dateTimeAt = textBox13.Text,
    };
        incident.lawEnforcementRequest = lawEnforcementRequest;
        int typecheck = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < o; i = i + 4)
        {
            serviceType test = new serviceType
            {
                sourceId = textBoxes[i].Text,
                type = cCheckedLists[typecheck].Text,
                name = textBoxes[i + 1].Text,
                version = textBoxes[i + 2].Text,
                description = textBoxes[i + 3].Text,
            };
            incident.serviceType.Add(test);
            typecheck++;
        }
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(incident, Formatting.Indented);//завершающая часть сохранения файла
    string filename = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filename, json);
    // System.Console.WriteLine(json);//вывод
    MessageBox.Show("Файл сохранен", "Успех!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Библиотека Json.Net которой вы пользуетесь поддерживает указание порядка полей:

```
[JsonProperty(Order = 1)]
```

Ну и расставьте вручную как вам надо:

```
class Incident
{
    [JsonProperty(Order = 10)]
    public string fincertId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Order = 20)]
    public string fixationAt { get; set; }
```

Хотя я не знаю, зачем такое нужно... При сериализации/десериализации порядок совершенно неважен на мой взгляд, разве что для чисто эстетической красоты.

А потом ещё если придётся поле в середину вклинивать... Поэтому в примере и сделал нумерацию "как в бейсике" - через десять, обычно хватает на некоторое время вставить между номерами без перенумерации при рефакторинге на скорую руку.

Comment: Делаю по одному документу, там распорядок важен