# Как правильно десериализовать json в объект C#?

Tags: c#, json

Вот пример json-а.

Можно получить тут https://opensky-network.org/api/states/all?lamin=51.421812&lomin=23.139124&lamax=55.961184&lomax=33.472494

или вот фрагмент

```
{
"time": 1556008469,
"states": [
    [
        "4248f4",
        "AFL2040 ",
        "United Kingdom",
        1556008469,
        1556008469,
        24.8216,
        52.5425,
        10363.2,
        false,
        236.66,
        233.75,
        0,
        null,
        10347.96,
        "5123",
        false,
        0
    ],
    [
        "471f82",
        "",
        "Hungary",
        1556008469,
        1556008469,
        26.7204,
        52.2582,
        10972.8,
        false,
        238.44,
        237.06,
        0,
        null,
        11003.28,
        "6230",
        false,
        0
    ]
]}
```

Я смог получить так сказать объект первого уровня, не знаю как достучатся дальше. Вот на картинке пример того что смог получить

[image]

Я пробывал еще раз распарсить полученную структуру, но там уже объект а не строка. И ступор. Вот код

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using QuickDeser;
using QuickDeser2;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://opensky-network.org/api/states/all?lamin=51.421812&lomin=23.139124&lamax=55.961184&lomax=33.472494");
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            Answer answer;
            SecondLevelDeser secondLevelDeser;
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    string fullJson = "";
                    string line = "";
                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        fullJson += line;
                    }
                   // Console.WriteLine(fullJson);
                    try
                    {
                        answer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Answer>(fullJson);
                        secondLevelDeser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SecondLevelDeser>(answer.ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine(answer);
                    }
                    catch (NullReferenceException e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Ничего нету");
                        throw;
                    }

                }     
            }
            response.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Запрос выполнен");
            Console.Read();
        }
      }
    }
```

Вот классы для десериализации

```
namespace QuickDeser
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public class Answer
    {
        public int time { get; set; }
        public List<List<object>> states { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

```
namespace QuickDeser2
{

    public class SecondLevelDeser
    {
        public List<object> state { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Полученный объект храниться в answer. А в этой строкой пробывал парсить secondLevelDeser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SecondLevelDeser>(answer.ToString());.

Comment: А в чём, собственно, проблема-то? И зачем вам вообще нужен SecondLevelDeser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это массив массивов.

```
var asdf1 = new string[] { "1asdf1", "1asdf2" };
var asdf2 = new string[] { "2asdf1", "2asdf2" };

var asdf = new[] {asdf1, asdf2 };
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(asdf).Dump();
```

Получите на выходе такую же структуру:

```
[["1asdf1","1asdf2"],["2asdf1","2asdf2"]]
```

Есть два варианта обработки подобного json.

Вот первый.

```
void Main()
{
    var data = this.GetData();
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(data);
    result.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public class Model
{
    public int time { get; set; }   

    [JsonProperty("states")]
    public string[][] States { get; set; }
}


private string GetData()
{
    return @"{
""time"": 1556008469,
""states"": [
    [
        ""4248f4"",
        ""AFL2040 "",
        ""United Kingdom"",
        1556008469
    ],
    [
        ""471f82"",
        ""Hungary"",
        ""Hungary123"",
        1556008469
    ]
]}";
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Минусы очевидны - потерялась информация о типах.

Второй вариант - парсить структуру, [примерно так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/954681/213987), основываясь не на названии полей, а [на порядке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/971817/213987) полей.

```
public class Model
{
    public int time { get; set; }   

    [JsonProperty("states")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(MyCustomConverter))]
    public IEnumerable<MyClass> States { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass
{
    [JsonProperty(Order = 0)]
    public string Asdf1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Order = 1)]
    public string Asdf2 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Order = 2)]
    public string Asdf3 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Order = 3)]
    public int Asdf4 { get; set; }
}

public class MyCustomConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Type type = (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) ?? objectType);
        bool isNullable = (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) != null);

        var token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token == null || token.Type == JTokenType.Null)
        {
            if (!isNullable)
                throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Null value for type {0} at path {1}", objectType.Name, reader.Path));

            return null;
        }

        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
        {
            return token.Select(x => this.Convert((JArray)x));
        }

        throw new Exception("Вот это вот сейчас неожиданно было");
    }

    private MyClass Convert(JArray arr)
    {
        return new MyClass
        {
            Asdf1 = (string)arr[0],
            Asdf2 = (string)arr[1],
            Asdf3 = (string)arr[2],
            Asdf4 = (int)arr[3],
        };
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Выдаёт правильный результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну вот как-то так (сильно не пинать, рефлексию не часто приходится использовать):

```
public class MyCustomConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Type type = (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) ?? objectType);
        bool isNullable = (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) != null);

        var token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token == null || token.Type == JTokenType.Null)
        {
            if (!isNullable)
                throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Null value for type {0} at path {1}", objectType.Name, reader.Path));

            return null;
        }

        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
        {
            return token.Select(x => this.Convert((JArray)x));
        }

        throw new Exception("Вот это вот сейчас неожиданно было");
    }

    private MyClass Convert(JArray val)
    {
        var result = new MyClass();

        var props = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties();
        var attrs = props.SelectMany(prop => (JsonPropertyAttribute[])prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(JsonPropertyAttribute), false));

        for(var i = 0; i < val.Count(); i++)
        {
            foreach (var prop in props)
            {
                var attr = prop.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(JsonPropertyAttribute));

                if(attr == null)
                    continue;

                var attJp = (JsonPropertyAttribute)attr;

                if(attJp.Order != i)
                    continue;

                switch(val[i].Type.ToString())
                {
                    case "String":
                        prop.SetValue(result, (string)val[i]);
                    break;
                    case "Integer":
                        prop.SetValue(result, (int)val[i]);
                    break;
                    default:
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В Вашем случае целевые данные идут не в виде объекта, а в виде массива массивов. Первый уровень массива - массив объектов. Второй уровень массива - сами данные.

В подобных ситуациях ИМХО вариант один. Использовать двойной цикл и в нём доставать данные.

Принцип примерно следующий:

```
ModelClass model = new ModelClass();
for(int i=0;i<=state.length-1;i++)
{
    List<object> item = state.get(i);
    for(int j=0;j<=item.length-1;j++)
    {
        switch(j)
        {
            case 0: model.A=item[j];break;
            case 1: model.B=item[j];break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Т.к. студии сейчас нет под рукой, писал на псевдокоде без проверки.**